# How to delete all GitLab files above 100 MB

Tags: github, gitlab, filesize

I am trying to import a Gitlab project to Github and have had it fail due to not being able to import files above 100 MB (this is a Github rule). I deleted the first one that caused a problem, but then upon restarting another file was too large. Is there any way to automate deleting all Gitlab projects above this threshold? Alternatively is there any way to look at the file size of all files in a list so I know which ones to manually delete?

Answer (score 1):

Did you stop tracking the file in git in addition to deleting it in your working directory? (i.e. using the command `git rm --cached yourlargefile`)? If not, the file is still being tracked, so it is still causing the import into Github to fail.

To answer your second question, calling `ls -l` from a terminal will list all the files in the working directory along with their file size in bytes, `ls -lh` will do the same, but with more human-readable file sizes (e.g. KB or MB, as applicable). If you need to scan your whole project, `ls -lhR` will recursively list all files in the entire directory tree.